# Conditions for equivalence of RKHS norm and $L^2(P)$ norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, st.statistics, kernels, learning-theory

Let $K$ be a psd kernel on an abstract space $X$ and let $H_K$ be the induced *Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS)*. Let $P$ be a probability measure on $X$ such that $H_K \subseteq L^2(P_X)$ and suppose the self-adjoint kernel integral operator $T_K:L^2(P) \to H_K$ defined by $(T_Kf)(x) := \int_X K(x,x') f(x')\,dP$ is compact.

> **Question 1.** Under what conditions on $K$ and $P$ does there exist a constant $0 < C < \infty$ such that
> $$
> \|f\|_{H_K} \le C\|f\|_{L^2(P)},
> $$
> for all $f \in H_K$ ?

In particular, I'm interested in the case where $X = \mathbb R^d$ and $P$ is the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R^d$.

### Observation

Note that one always has $\|f\|_{H_K} = \|T_K^{1/2} f\|_{L^2(P)} \le \sqrt{\|T_K\|_{op}}\|f\|_{H_K}$ for any $f \in H_K$. Indeed,

It is well-known from [Mercer's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Integral_operators_and_Mercer%27s_theorem) that if $T_K f := \sum_n \lambda_n \langle f,\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}$ is the spectral decomposition of $T_K$ (where the $\phi_n$'s are an orthonormal basis for $L^2(P)$), then the inner-product in $H_K$ is given by
$$
\langle f,g\rangle_{H_K} = \sum_n \frac{\langle f,\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}\langle g,\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}}{\lambda_n}, 
$$
and moreover $H_K$ is given by
$$
H_K = \left\{f \in L^2(P) \mid \sum_n \frac{\langle f,\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}^2}{\lambda_n} < \infty\right\}.
$$

One then deduces that
$$
\begin{split}
\|T_K^{1/2} f\|_{H_k}^2 &= \langle T_K^{1/2}f,T_K^{1/2} f\rangle_{H_k} = \langle f,T_K f\rangle_{H_k}\\
& = \sum_n \dfrac{\langle f,\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}\langle T_K f,\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}}{\lambda_n}\\
& = \sum_n \dfrac{\langle f,\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}\langle f,T_K\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}}{\lambda_n}\\
&= \sum_n \langle f,\phi_n\rangle_{L^2(P)}^2 = \|f\|_{L^2(P)}^2.
\end{split}
$$

Thus, $\|f\|_{L^2(P)} = \|T_K^{1/2}f\|_{H_K} \le \sqrt{\|T_K\|_{op}}\|f\|_{H_K}$.

Comment: You need at least that $\int_X K(x,x)dP(x) = \infty$. So in most practical cases the answer for your question is that such thing does not happen.

Comment: Indeed, this makes sense. Thanks!